# Hosting my own forms with captcha in Mailchimp

Tags: forms, captcha, mailchimp

I really have been struggling with finding the answers to this question.

I have embeded a form with Mailchimp inside my own website, the form has all the fields I pulled from the source of the default mailchimp sign-up form except the captcha section as my domain is different of that of Mailchimp.

The problem is that every time I want to submit the form it is redirected to the mailchimp form via the action:

```
<form action="http://mydomain.us10.list-manage.com/subscribe/post" method="post">
```

and once it gets there it forces me to do redo the captcha because it throws an error.

How do I keep the entire form submission process within my own website and only use the form fields and submission directly to Mailchimp's database without having to go via their default form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mailchimp captch integration not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332066/mailchimp-captch-integration-not-working)

Comment: Not quite, as in here I am asking how to host my own submission process. Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to know what error is being thrown by MailChimp.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix this problem by making sure to have a separate CAPTCHA ID for my domain.